# Passando POST Assíncrono, array retorna 0

Tags: php, ajax

Estou tentando passar os dados de um Form para outra página, :
Meu Option está fazendo uma consulta no Mysql para retornar os valores dentro das opções do option.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
                  <div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                      <label>Nome da Impressora</label>
                      <?php 
                      //include "config.php";
                      //clausula sql
                      $sql = "SELECT * FROM bd_print order by id";

                      //executa a clausula sql
                      $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql)or die("Falha na execução da instrução SQL!");
                      ?>
                         <select name="nome_imp" class="form-control" id="tabela">  
                            <option select> Selecione ...</option>
                         <?php

                            while($dados = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                            {
                                echo "<option value='".$dados['nome']."'>".$dados['nome']."</option>";
                            }

                            echo "</select>";

                        ?>
                         </select>
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <button type="button" id="remover" class="botao btn btn-primary" />Remover</button>
                </form>
```

Segue o código responsável pela execução do script php;

```
$(".botao").click(function(){
    var vNome = $("#nome_imp").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: { 
            nome_imp : vNome            

            },

            url: "function/rmv_func.php",
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(result){
                $("#respostabla").html('');
                $("#respostabla").append(result);
            },
            beforeSend: function(){
                $('#resposta').css({display:"block"});
            },
            complete: function(msg){
                $('#resposta').css({display:"none"});

            }
        });

    });
```

O que acontece é que o retorno do post é "undefined index "nome_imp", ou seja, o post não está sendo passado. Se faço o action direto pelo FORM, ele passa o POST.
Acredito que o meu erro seja na sintaxe do ajax, porém nao estou conseguindo identificar onde.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não seria porque você está tentando buscar o input com a query `#nome_imp`, sendo que o id dele é na verdade `tabela`?

Tente trocar o

```
var vNome = $("#nome_imp").val();
```

para

```
var vNome = $("#tabela").val();
```

Comment: Corretissímo, foi um erro primario meu nao reparar nisso, mas obrigado por disponibilizar tempo e me mostrar, obrigado !!!

Answer (score 0):

Repare que seu select possui o name = `nome_imp` e id = `tabela`. Quando passa o post pelo form direto, o PHP identifica o name correto

Você deveria usar em seu jQuery:

```
var vNome = $("#tabela").val();
```

Comment: Correto também, obrigado pelo feedback !!!